# plist type:dictionay to UITableView

Tags: uitableview, dictionary, plist

My "Property List2" are below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Police</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>PoliceStation</string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>PoliceStation.png</string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <string>1241241244</string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>TaichungNorth</string>
    </dict>
        <key>Fire</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>FireFighter</string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>FireFighter.png</string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <string>21324124</string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>TaichungEast</string>
    </dict>
        <key>Taichung</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>TaichungGovernment</string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>TaichungGovernment.jpg</string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <string>3252342342</string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>TaichungWest</string>
    </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

How to load each "UserName" and "Image" into UITableView ？ especially when type are "dictionary' not 'array' ??

The UITableview will show each "UserName" text in Center and each "Image" on the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse plist to a dictonary:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"plist"];  
NSDictionary *objects = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Than you can iterate all keys and create objects for presenting in table view:

```
NSMutableArray *parsedObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
[objects enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    Object *object = [[Object alloc] init];
    [object setUserName:obj[@"UserName"]];
    ...
    [parsedObjects addObject:object];
}];
```

Than you should implement tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     ...
     Object *object = parsedObjects[indexPath.row];
     [cell setObject:object];

     return cell;
  }
```

And implement data showing in cell.

Comment: Hello,AIKo.
I have question with the code :
    `Object *object = [[Object alloc] init];
    [object setUserName:obj[@"UserName"]];`
What is Object for? Is it for UITableView ？
and object is for? and there isn't a method called setUserName..
Sorry for I've just Learned iOS Programming for 1 months..
Please help, thanks!!